# E-mail regular expression which does not allow “:” and “;” characters

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation, email

\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*.\w+([-.]\w+)*

I have this regular expression and I would like to update it in order to prevent the end user to enter “:” and “;” characters.

Comment: https://www.regex101.com/

Comment: I can't see anything in that regex that matches colons or semicolons.

Comment: please try this "test;test@example.com".. it will pass it

Comment: Of course it will: the regexp is matching test@example.com - not the whole string

Comment: I need it not to pass email like "test;test@example.com"

Comment: Add ^ to the start and $ to the end

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Alex Brown i did your suggestion and it works fine.

^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*.\w+([-.]\w+)*$